# How do I automatically compile coffeescript in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, coffeescript, compojure

I'm building a web application with compojure and Leiningen 2. Is there a way to automatically compile coffeescript into javascript like Ruby on Rails does with sprocket?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you are looking for?  `coffee --compile --watch src/` auto compiles whenever a coffeescript file changes, editors like emacs typically have "compile-on-save" features, and if you really wanted to do it all from clojure, you could use the `java.nio.file` watch service API.

Comment: Something like the :prep-tasks from this post. http://blog.arc90.com/2012/07/19/compile-your-coffeescript-along-with-your-clojure/

But I guess I can use --watch. Never knew coffeescript had that built in. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your're familiar with the rails asset pipeline, take a look at Dieter (https://github.com/edgecase/dieter). It's ring middleware which allows for coffee, sass, less, haml, etc. compilation.

You won't need to `watch` or manually compile files every time.

Comment: Could you go into more detail on how to implement it? I've setup the middleware and now I'm lost as how to to name my files and get it to compile. Also, when I evaluate link-to-asset it returns nil.

Comment: We will need more information about your project's structure. Is the code open source and on Github? Maybe it'd be easier to fix if I can try it myself.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/vbauer/lein-coffeescript - A Leiningen plugin for running CoffeeScript compiler.